# How do I set the main text far left in Bootstrap 4 cover template?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to get the following text, set on the far left of the page, but all I get is centered text.

"Cover your page.
Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own."

How do I get this text on the far left?

Example is found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/cover/

CSS is found here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/cover/cover.css

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried providing Bootstrap4 class float-left to your div?

Answer (score 0):

add `margin-left:-200px;` below `float:left;`